# Suggested edit not reviewable

Tags: bug, review-queues

There is an edit made by community, which defaces the original post, which I can't review ("This item is not reviewable") :

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8317895

I'm assuming it's a test to see if I'm paying attention (with a bug), but I may be wrong.

Comment: Duplicate of an unanswered question. Fantastic.

Comment: Ranting on a year-old post. Awesome.

Comment: The beauty of the StackExchange network is that the content never dies, so the age of a post is irrelevant.