# Suggested Edit - No Longer Reviewable

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I've just made a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13162383) to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654915/split-string-into-array-regex-php) to address some of the formatting and clarity issues that there appeared to be in this question.

I checked back to see if the edit had been approved/rejected but instead the status appears to be 'This item is no longer reviewable'. I had a search on Meta and found [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277130/this-item-is-no-longer-reviewable-on-an-ended-review) [similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296012/suggested-edit-not-reviewable) questions but both of these seemed to occur when it was an audit or if the item was no longer eligible to be in that queue.

I've checked and the question has not been deleted but has been edited by the author. I've seen before that you can have an edit which 'clashes' with another but that always seems to appear in the review status informing me what has happened. There seems to be no record of this edit anywhere within the edit history.

**Is this normal behaviour? Am I missing something here?**

---

**Update**: Interestingly, if I view all of the suggested edits I've made it does class this specific one as 'rejected edit' but when viewing that revision, it doesn't show up as rejected.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the post made an edit in the same minute as you did. You can check this in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38654915/revisions) of the post. What happens then is basically Undefined Behaviour - sometimes, you see a message 'the edit could not be submitted', sometimes the suggested edit is automatically rejected. This ('no longer reviewable') is apparently another possible outcome.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! Is this a bug then? It didn't seem to be a great user experience because I've ended up here...

Comment: @Henders I don't know. Race conditions are inevitable to happen and it's hard to account for them.

Comment: @henders if meta is any proof, having edits rejected is **never** a good user experience no matter how you have to find out.

Comment: @Gimby If a suggested edit is low quality, why it should lead to "_good user experience_"? This is true regardless of rep scores. :)

Comment: @sambul35 in this case however, the suggested edit wasn't of low quality, it just conflicted with an edit made by the author... Even in a situation where it was low quality, how can you improve your performance if you aren't informed that your edit was low quality?

Comment: @Henders I completely agree re low educational value of reject votes, not supplemented by anonymous comments. In your case, as the above answer hints, it was likely a system glitch. IMO your suggested edit was aimed to improve the question. Hope, it was not supplemented by a downvote, as I see no point to hummer someone's rep for low gramma, typical for non-native English speakers. :)